# redirecting to another page while downloading the excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, export-to-excel, httpresponse

I am trying to hide the progress bar after download of excel has happen in a page where Grid data need to be exported, but its not happening when i click on the **downloadtoexcel** button i am able to see the loading image and after downloaded the file also i am able to see the image(**divProgress Image**) and I am not able to click any thing after that because of this image on the page....

For this I have redirected to another page like when i click on the **button** 
another page will be open and there I will be downloading the excel...

but I am not able to get the grid data rather i am getting HTML page contents in the excel file .....

this is my function for exporting the grid data to excel

```
if (gvPR.Attributes["FilterQuery"].Equals(string.Empty))
{
    GridData = objCert.GetCerts(remoteUser,TotalRecords, 1, Filter);
}
else
{
    GridData = objCert.GetCerts(remoteUser,gvPR.PageSize, 1, Filter);
}
Session["OutPut"] = GridData;
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open('/MasterPages/Default.aspx');", true);
//DatasettoExcel.Convert(GridData, Response);
```

and the below code is for downloading excel in different page (Default.aspx)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();        
    Response.Charset = "";        
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Download" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHMMss") + ".xls");

    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();      
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite); 
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid dg = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid();  
    DataSet ds = Session["OutPut"] as DataSet;
    dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    dg.DataBind();
    dg.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();

  }
```

I am not sure where I am doing wrong in this function....
I am not able to export the grid data instead of this getting html content for this page.. this is content page derived from MasterPage...

would any one please help me on this issue .. 
Many thanks in advance.....

Comment: Problem is due to use of Response.End(). Means all response is end from server.

Comment: Warning! You're not generating proper Excel files. You're sending HTML to the client masquerading as a `.xls` file, which has some bad side effects. I [blog](https://masonmcg.com/blog/entry/properly-generating-excel-files-in-net) about how to properly generate Excel files in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Add a redirect header

```
Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "5; url=yourpage.html");
Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
```

after 5 sec delay and redirect to yourpage.html